# C# socket programming problem [receive file has a different hash]

Tags: c#, sockets

I have socket program which sends a **file** from **socket client** to **socket server** and create the file on the server

**There is no problem in sending the file to the server**... **[Not corrupted]**

But,

Im my code : (Server listening and  receive data )

```
this.buffer = new byte[1000000];
 this.DataSocket.Receive(this.buffer, this.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
```

So always `1000000` bytes are received from the **client** to **server** which always the file created in the server has a fix size value .. also larger than the original file.

most fuzzy thing is file `MD5` hashes are different... because of this fixed buffer as i think

my problem is how i cant send the file to the **server** with the same `MD5` Hash ?

Comment: `Receive()` should be handing you back the length of received bytes. Use that to truncate the file you're storing, or use a loop to keep reading until an EOF (or EOS) is returned.

Comment: Well, let's start with what datatype `this.DataSocket` is.

Comment: great got it ;) will check and come back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be because the MD5 is begin created with the entire buffer you have created. If the data is only 50000 bytes long but the buffer is 1000000 I assume these would create different hash values.

If I remember correctly the receive method returns an int which should be the size of the data that you have received. You could create a new byte array and copy the received data into an array which is the exact same size as the original file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to go crazy on the buffer, you can read it in portions. You can also use a `MemoryStream` to hold all the collected information while you receive it in:

```
MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream();
this.buffer = new byte[1024];

int BytesRead = this.DataSocket.Receive(this.buffer, this.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
while (BytesRead > 0)
{
  MemStream.Write(this.buffer, 0, this.buffer.Length);
  BytesRead = this.DataSocket.Receive(this.buffer, this.buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
}
```